# Using a custom parameter in train_step() method of a VAE, which is different for each epoch

Tags: python, tensorflow, autoencoder

I am trying to build a VAE, similar to the example here: https://keras.io/examples/generative/vae/
However, I am employing a custom loss in the model and I would like this loss to be multiplied by a factor that increases with progressing epochs. I did it by defining at the beginning

```
def __init__(self, encoder, decoder, **kwargs):
    self.eloss_weight = tf.Variable(initial_value=args.eloss_weight, trainable=False)
```

compiled the model to run eagerly

```
vae.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(jit_compile=False), run_eagerly=True)
```

and when fitting I change the value of the energy loss weight using a callback like this

```
def eloss_weight_increase(epoch, logs):
    vae.eloss_weight = vae.eloss_weight + 1


increase_eloss_weight = tf.keras.callbacks.LambdaCallback(on_epoch_end=eloss_weight_increase)

vae.fit(
    X_train, V_train, batch_size=args.batch_size, epochs=args.epochs,
    callbacks=[increase_eloss_weight], verbose=1,)
```

I had to use run_eagerly, because if I did not, in train_step, when the parameter was called as self.eloss_weight, it did not look if it was changed or not (I guess in order optimize the model to be as fast as possible, when test_step was compiled, it just remembered the exact value and stopped thinking of it as a variable). However, because of run_eagerly it now runs 4 times slower (which is pretty bad, before this, the model took 4.5 hours to train, now it is almost a day). Is there any way to do this thing without using run_eagerly=True?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vae.eloss_weight = vae.eloss_weight + 1` overwrites a `Variable` by a `Tensor` (not the same). You should use a variable's `assign` method to keep the `Variable` object intact:

```
vae.eloss_weight.assign(vae.eloss_weight + 1.)
```

or

```
vae.eloss_weight.assign_add(1.)
```

I have used this myself before, so it should work (also without eager execution).